# jquery dialog box , element id not getting recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery

My requirement is when i click on the image show.gif, jquery dialog box should open. "id" is not getting recognised in jquery function.
Below is my code:

```
  var history = function(value, rowIndex) {
                var STID = this.grid.getItem(rowIndex).STID;
    var str = "<img src=<%=request.getContextPath()%>/img/show.gif width=\"20\" height=\"20\" id=\"showDialog\">";
              return str;
            };
```

below is the jquery function:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false
    });
    $("#showDialog").on("click", function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    });
});

</script>
```

When i click on show.gif, it has to display jquery dialog box, where iam going wrong, i have declared id="showDialog" in function, still "id" is not getting recognized. Do i need to add any quotes. Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: When is that `img` tag being added to the page?  If it's after the page loads then it wouldn't have existed when jQuery tried to bind the click event.

Comment: I would like to see some of the dialog html.

Comment: Rather than escaping double quotes, why not use single quotes for the attributes?

Comment: @David - oh ok. probably "img" is loading after the jquery function is invoked, please see my entire code in jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/W8aGF/ . Iam using dojo for getting the results in enhanced grid and jquery to show the dialog box.

Comment: @MikeCheel , please see in jsfiddle.net/W8aGF. Thanks

Comment: @J.Wells , i tried it still it was not woring. may be the jquery function loads before the html is getting loaded, not sure...

Comment: Why does the fiddle say no js for its library?

Comment: @user3633028: I'm not familiar with dojo, but from the code it definitely looks like the element is being added *after* the jQuery selector runs, so you're never actually binding a click event to `#showDialog`.  You'll either need to bind to an unchanging parent element (`document` often works) and filter for `#showDialog`, or bind to `#showDialog` *after* it's added to the page.

Answer (score 0):

you need quotes try to change this:

```
var str = "<img src=<%=request.getContextPath()%>/img/show.gif width=\"20\" height=\"20\" id=\"showDialog\">";
```

to this:

```
var str = "<img src=<%=request.getContextPath()%>/img/show.gif width=\"20\" height=\"20\" id='showDialog'>";
```

Comment: Alessandro Minoccheri -no still its not recognizing.

Comment: Alessandro Minoccheri  - no still its not working, please see my entire code in jsfiddle "jsfiddle.net/W8aGF" .

Comment: Thanks all, it worked. i added javascript function and added onclick to call that javascript function.var history = function(value, rowIndex) {
                var STID = this.grid.getItem(rowIndex).STID;
    var str = "<img src=<%=request.getContextPath()%>/img/show.gif width=\"20\" height=\"20\" id=\"showDialog\" onClick=\"show()\">";
              return str;
            };